# Adding google.maps.event.addListener in a loop with named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I appreciate there is a common issue with scoping in loops within javascript, but I can't work out this particular issue. I have a loop of click listeners to add to my map, I want to call a function to do it:

```
function addInfoListener(name,map){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<p>"+name+"</p>",
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });                     
    }

$.each(polygons, function(index, value){
            addInfoListener(controller.getCragName(index),map);
});
```

However the click listener doesn't seem to get created. If I do it in an anonymous function it works as expected:

```
$.each(polygons, function(index, value){
        google.maps.event.addListener(value, 'click', function(e){infoWindow.setContent("<p>"+controller.getCragName(index)+"</p>");                                                                     
                                                                 infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);});
        infoWindow.open(this.map);                                                                          
    });
```

The complete problem is described in this JSFiddle with the preferred solution commented out (as it is it works as I'd like). Can you help me to rewrite this part of the code in an accepted manner.

http://jsfiddle.net/eatxt3od/

Comment: Why was that question downvoted? Cannot see any reason why ...

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple click-event-listeners on the map, producing multiple infowindows? It seems to be "right" to have handlers on the polygons themselves and reuse the infowindow.

Comment: Either suits me I was just doing it as an exercise in using JavaScript/Maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to listen for clicks on the polygons, not on the map
2. javascript is case sensitive (infoWindow and infowindow are different)

   ```
   function addInfoListener(polygon, name, map) {
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: "<p>" + name + "</p>"
       });
       google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (e) {
           infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
           infowindow.open(map);
       });
       console.dir(map);
   }

   $.each(polygons, function (index, value) {
       addInfoListener(value, controller.getCragName(index), map);
   });
   ```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eatxt3od/1/)

code snippet:

```js
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;

/* ======= Model ======= */

var model = {

  crags: [{
    name: "Stanage",
    cragColor: "'#FF0000'",
    coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.360470, -1.646050),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.359523, -1.647895),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.351006, -1.637123),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.351364, -1.627167)
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Burbage",
    cragColor: "'#00AA00'",
    coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.341489, -1.606224),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.338148, -1.605190),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.338145, -1.600849),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.341501, -1.604020)
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Higgar",
    cragColor: "'#0000BB'",
    coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.340912, -1.611288),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.338048, -1.612833),
      new google.maps.LatLng(53.339762, -1.608670)
    ]
  }]
};

/* ======= Controller ======= */

var controller = {

  init: function() {

    mapView.init();
  },

  getStanageCoords: function() {
    return model.stanageCoords;
  },

  getBurbageCoords: function() {
    return model.burbageCoords;
  },

  getCrags: function() {
    return model.crags;
  },

  getCragName: function(index) {
    return model.crags[index].name;
  }
};

/* ======= View ======= */
var mapView = {
  polygons: [],

  init: function() {
    this.drawMap();
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log("Rendering map view");
  },

  drawMap: function() {
    var polygons = new Array();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_view"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3472915, -1.633261),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    $.each(controller.getCrags(), function(index, value) {
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: value.coords,
        strokeColor: value.cragColor,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: value.cragColor,
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      polygons.push(polygon);
      polygon.setMap(map);

    });

    function addInfoListener(polygon, name, map) {
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<p>" + name + "</p>"
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e) {
        infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
      });
      console.dir(map);
    }

    $.each(polygons, function(index, value) {
      addInfoListener(value, controller.getCragName(index), map);
    });
  }
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  controller.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_view" style="height: 800px; width: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: I would also recommend attaching the `crags.name`  directly to the polygons, instead of this `getCragName` function.